# i cant specify a user to access my post in django

Tags: django-views, django-templates

its a bit tricky for i tried solving it but cant,i am using class based views with customuser model, i have a blog post with multiple user i want to make it in a way only the main authour of a post should be allowed to delete or update post but i dont seems to know what to do or how to set it,here is my code kindly take a glance and release me from debugging,instead i get what i want wont get nothing and inatead i get something every author has the right to delete each other's post plus this is how i want it to look like when the user view its blog_detail but for non user it should be blank [![enter image description here][1]][1]

### views.py

```
class BlogUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Blog
    fields = ['title', 'categories', 'overview', 'thumbnail', 'summary']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = Doctor.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        blog = Doctor.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        if self.request.user == blog.user:
            return True
        return False


class BlogDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Blog
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog')

    def test_func(self):
        blog = Doctor.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        if self.request.user == blog.user:
            return True
        return False
```

### blog_detail.html

```
{% extends "pages/base.html" %}
    {% load static %}


    {% block title %}Jazeera Blog{% endblock title %}

    {% block meta %} the best medical-service website in Abuja {% endblock meta %}
    {% block content %}

         <br><p></p>
    <section class="ftco-section bg-light" id="blog-section">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5 pb-5">
              <div class="col-md-10 heading-section text-center ftco-animate">
                <h2 class="mb-4">Gets Every Single Updates Here</h2>
                <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia</p>
              </div>
            </div>


          <div class="container">
             <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5 pb-5">
              <div class="col-lg-8 ftco-animate">

                <h2 class="text-center">{{ object.title }}</h2>
                <div class="meta mb-3 text-center">
               <div><h6><span><a href = "">written By {{ object.user }}</span><small class="date"><i class="icon-clock"></i>  {{  object.timestamp|timesince }} ago</small><a/></h6>
                </div>
                </div>
               <div><small class="icon-eye text-danger">{{ object.view_count }}</small></div> 
              <div class="meta mb-3 text-center">
              <h5>{% for cat in object.categories.all %}<span class="btn btn-dark">{{ cat }}</span> {% endfor %}</h5>
              </div>
               <p class="text-center">{{ object.overview }}</p>
               {% if object.created_by == user %}
                <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt mb-2" href="{% url 'blog-update' blog.id %}">Update</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt mb-2" href="{% url 'blog-delete' blog.id %}">Delete</a>
                {% endif %}
                </div>
               </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

    {% endblock content  %}
```

##urls.py

```
    path('blog/', BlogListView.as_view(), name='blog'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='blog-detail'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>/update/', BlogUpdateView.as_view(), name='blog-update'),
    path('blog/new/', BlogCreateView.as_view(), name='blog-create'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>/delete/', BlogDeleteView.as_view(), name='blog-delete'),

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aojDX.jpg
```

Comment: I assume you render the template in some `{% for ... %}` loop?

Comment: kindly elaborate on the 
{% for loop .... %}

Comment: the `{% endif %}` is shown multiple times, so that (likely) means there is some looping mechanism that you did not share?

Comment: what if you (temporarily) remove the categories, and other `{% for ... %}` loops?

Comment: @Chosebrain: what I mean is that you first should look for the "sources" of the `{% endif %}`. Try to inspect the page source, to look where the `{% endif %}` are coming from.

Comment: Well if {% end if %} were to show multiple times it would have shown me an error but beside I don't have  endif,hope you can find another solution please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the set of `Blog` objects in the queryset to the ones that are written by the `request.user`:

```
class BlogDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Blog
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog')

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            user=self.request.user
        )
```

This will return a HTTP 404 error, if a user aims to remove a `Blog` object `post` where the `post.user` is not the logged in user.

Comment: thanks but its not still working it actually did show me a common error which i did return back to my normal view

Comment: @Chosenbrain: well the rendering problem is evidently not fixed with that. This is more to prevent a malicious POST request. as for the rendering, if I try this locally, I don't see an `{% endif %}`, likely it is caused by an outer `{% for ... %}` loop (can you show exactly what template you use to render *all* items). Edit your question.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem i did not use any for loop on the detail i only use {% for %} on my main blog list

Comment: yes i used {% for } its just for category will it affect? @Willem Van Onsem

Comment: i removed its not helping rather it destroy categories as expected by me

Answer (score 1):

In your views (BlogUpdateView and BlogDeleteView), update test_func to become;

```py
def test_func(self):
    blog = Doctor.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.pk)
    return self.request.user == blog.user
```

If you're testing for one condition in multiple views as you just did, it will be better creating a separate class for the test. Say, `IsOwnerMixin` where you perform the test and then inherit it in the required view(s).

Additionally, you can change `{% if object.user == user %}` in your blog_detail.html to become `{% if user.is_authenticated and object.user == request.user %}`

Good luck!

Comment: thanks but still the same just that whn i change my views i get error when i try going to the delete url

Comment: Update your question with relevant urls.py

Comment: i did that before and they are relevant

Comment: In your post, I can only see the views.py file and blog_detail.html file. Add the urls.py file to help you link it properly. You didn't specify the type of error you get when visiting the delete view

Comment: I do not get any errors,I just get random post deleted or updated as far as I am login